# Two separate Functions, but I want them to be initialized at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these 2 separate functions, each work and are initialized by 2 different input buttons which are used to pass two different Country Names to create a html table comparison of the 2 countries from a SQL database.

How can I rewrite this to initialize both function together with 1 button not 2?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function display_results_table() {
            $("medal_table").empty();
            $('<table id = "results_table">').appendTo('#medal_table');
            $.get("sam2.php", { Country_1: $('#Country_1').val(), Country_2: $('#Country_2').val(), queryType: $('#differentOptions').val() }, 

        function (results_obtained) {

            $('<tr><td>Rank</td>' +
            '<td>Country Name</td>' +
            '<td>Gold</td>' +
            '<td>Silver</td>' +
            '<td>Bronze</td>' +
            '<td>Total</td></tr>').appendTo('#results_table');

            for (var i = 0; i <= results_obtained.length; i++) {
                $('<tr><td>' + (i+1) + '</td>' + 
                '<td>' + results_obtained[i].country_name + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + results_obtained[i].gold + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + results_obtained[i].silver + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + results_obtained[i].bronze + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + results_obtained[i].total + '</td></tr>').appendTo('#results_table');              
            }   
        },'json');

        $('</table>').appendTo('#medal_table');
        }

        function display_cyclist_results_table() {
            $("cyclist_table").empty();
            $('<table id = "cyclist_results_table">').appendTo('#cyclist_table');
            $.get("sam3.php", { Country_1: $('#Country_1').val(), Country_2: $('#Country_2').val(), queryType: $('#differentOptions').val() }, 

        function (cyclist_results_obtained) {

            $('<tr><td>Name</td></tr>').appendTo('#cyclist_results_table');

            for (var j = 0; j <= cyclist_results_obtained.length; j++) {
                $('<tr><td>' + cyclist_results_obtained[j].iso_id + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + cyclist_results_obtained[j].name + '</td></tr>').appendTo('#cyclist_results_table');
            }

        },'json');

        $('</table>').appendTo('#cyclist_table');
        }

    </script>
    <title>sam.php</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form">
        <table>
            <tr><td><input name="Country_1" id="Country_1" value="GBR" type="text"></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input name="Country_2" id="Country_2" value="USA" type="text"></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="button" value="Medal Comparison" onClick="display_results_table()"/></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="Cyclist Comparison" onClick="display_cyclist_results_table()"/></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <div id="medal_table"></div>
    <div id="cyclist_table"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it into a function

```
function call_everybody(){
    display_results_table();
    display_cyclist_results_table();
}
```

So your button just need this

```
<input type="button" value="Cyclist Comparison" onclick="call_everybody()"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `on()` or `click()` function on a new button (or any element you want):

```
$('#button').click(function() {
   functionOne();
   functionTwo();
});
```

Comment: A delegated event handler, for a single ID matched element, seems very wasteful. I love delegated handlers but this is overkill. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a jQuery handler instead of inline `onclick` handlers:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    display_results_table();
    display_cyclist_results_table();
});
```

Inline handlers separate the event registration from the event handler for no good reason. This is easier to maintain.

This just requires a way to identify the button (e.g. an ID added to it):

```
<input id="button1" type="button" value="Medal Comparison" />
```